# SQL how to query multiple tables as if they are one continuous table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 6 tables that have different columns but share a unique foreign key. How do i merge all the columns given a foreign key, but padded with NULL if the row doesn't exist. Here 3 tables are shown

```
               table1                           table2                                table3
    | my_data  | foreign_key_id |    | my_data  | foreign_key_id |    | my_data  | more_data | foreign_key_id |
    | -------- | -------------- |    | -------- | -------------- |    | -------- | --------- | -------------- |
    | first    | 1              |    | erste    | 1              |    | første   | 400       | 1              |
    | second   | 2              |                                     | anden    | 720       | 2              |
```

The desired output for `foreign_key_id=2`  should be:

```
    | table1_my_data | table2_my_data | table3_my_data  | table3_more_data |
    | -------------- | -------------- | --------------- | ---------------- |
    | second         | NULL           | anden           | 720              |
```

**How do I achieve this, with a solution that scales for more tables (up to 6)?**

Here is some code for MySQL to reproduce the tables

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    my_data VARCHAR(20),
    foreign_key_id INT UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    my_data VARCHAR(20),
    foreign_key_id INT UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE table3 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    my_data VARCHAR(20),
    more_data INT,
    foreign_key_id INT UNIQUE
);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(null, 'first', 1);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(null, 'second', 2);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(null, 'erste', 1);
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(null, 'første', 400, 1);
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(null, 'anden', 720, 2);
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried to use joins the problem with joins however is that tables only join on one common column and in this problem the foreign_key_id is either equal to one another or NULL. In short: join only works if none of the tables are missing a row.

```
SELECT t1.my_data, t2.my_data, t3.my_data, t3.more_data
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.foreign_key_id = t2.foreign_key_id
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.foreign_key_id = t3.foreign_key_id
WHERE t1.foreign_key_id=2
```

I have also tried using unions

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` LEFT OUTER JOIN `table2` ON (0) LEFT OUTER JOIN `table3` ON (0) WHERE table1.foreign_key_id='2'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `table1` RIGHT OUTER JOIN `table2` ON (0) LEFT OUTER JOIN `table3` ON (0) WHERE table2.foreign_key_id='2'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `table1` LEFT OUTER JOIN `table2` ON (0) RIGHT OUTER JOIN `table3` ON (0) WHERE table3.foreign_key_id='2';
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - although it seems like you just want a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given sample data the following meets your desired result:

```
SELECT t1.my_data, t2.my_data, t3.my_data, t3.more_data
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.foreign_key_id = t2.foreign_key_id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.foreign_key_id = t3.foreign_key_id
WHERE t1.foreign_key_id=2
;

+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| my_data | my_data | my_data | more_data |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| second  | null    | anden   |       720 |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

However as these are all foreign keys I suggest you should use the source of those keys as the main table and left join all the others to that so that there will always be at least one row to allow any values in any joined tables to be returned. Let's call that table T

```
SELECT t1.my_data t1_data, t2.my_data t2_data, t3.my_data t3_data, t3.more_data
FROM t
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t.id = t2.foreign_key_id
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t.id = t2.foreign_key_id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t.id = t3.foreign_key_id
WHERE t1.id=2
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT t1.my_data, t2.my_data, t3.my_data, t3.more_data
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.foreign_key_id = t2.foreign_key_id
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.foreign_key_id = t3.foreign_key_id
# Here you can add the other three tables with INNER JOIN
WHERE t1.foreign_key_id=2
```

I think this should work for all the tables you want to query.

Comment: Also here: the problem with this solution is that it doesn't work if the first table doesn't contain a row having foreign_key_id=2

Comment: Do you need the data from the table does not have the foreign key? But the query should work an you will see `None` or `NULL`. And if `table1` doesn't have a foreign key of 2 you can change the `WHERE` clause to table that has it `t2.foreign_key_id=2`.

Comment: I am not completely clear on what you are asking. But i need the data from all the tables that have a row with the foreign key, some of the tables are allowed to not have a row containing the foreign key and should return NULL instead, just like table2 id=2 in my example

Comment: So when you run the mentioned query what are your results? For the table that doesn't have the condition in the `WHERE` clause you should get `NULL` or `None` as a result for that table.

Comment: When i run your query i get an Empty set (No results) But what I really want is 1 row where the columns for t2 are NULL, just like i specified in my question as "the desired output"

Comment: For your request to be true there has to be a row in `table2` with a value `NULL` and `foreign_key = 2` otherwise you will get as you said `no results`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to innerjoin the data of the tables to get that output.

for example this query get the data you need.

```
SELECT  t1.my_data, t2.my_data, t3.my_data, t3.other_data FROM table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.foreign_key_id = t2.foreign_key_id INNER JOIN table3 as t3 ON t1.foreign_key_id = t3.foreign_key_id WHERE t1.foreign_key_id = 1;
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't work if the first table doesn't contain a row having foreign_key_id=1

Comment: In that case you can use subqueries if need to find coincidences on each table.